# How to read in an array with tuples from a yaml file with ROS?

Tags: c++, yaml, ros

I have a yaml-file like this:

```
object_0:
  - v: 1.55
  - t_x: 110.281
  - t_y: 367.959
  - traj_const_dist: 1.0
  - trajectory: [[117, 356], [116, 356], [115, 356], [114, 356], [113, 356], [113, 357], [113, 358], [113, 359], [113, 360]]
```

The parameter `trajectory` is defined like this: `std::vector<std::pair<double,double>> trajectory_;`

When I read in the parameters:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh_;
nh_.param<std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>>(obj_topic, trajectory_, std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>());
```

... I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::getParam(const string&, std::vector<std::pair<double, double> >&) const’
       if (getParam(param_name, param_val))
```

It would help if you give me suggestions. Is the data type `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>>` not correct?

(Sorry, it is a huge project and difficult to make a small and compilable example. I will do a small one if you insist on it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by making use of XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue

Assuming the parameters in yaml file already loaded to parameter server,the following code snippet can be used:

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue trajectory;
nh_.getParam("/param_name", trajectory);
   
/*To ensure the reading will happen if the data is provided in right format*/
if (trajectory.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < trajectory.size(); i++)
    {
        XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue trajectoryObject = trajectory[i];

        /*Individual coordinate points in trajectory*/

        int xCoordinate = trajectoryObject[0];
        int yCoordinate = trajectoryObject[1];
        ROS_INFO("The %d  th coordinate values are : %d and %d", ixCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html) there is not any function `getParam` to get vector of pairs or vector of vectors. So, you need to change your YAML file and use only existing functions `getParam`.

Comment: If you click on the function `param()` then you can see in the library, there is a `getParam`. Within the library comes this error.

Comment: @j35t3r `param()` is a template function which calls `getParam()` depending on the template type. But there is limited set of signatures of `getParam()`. So, you need to use such types in `param()` which are corresponding to existing  `getParam()`. "error: no matching function" means corresponding function doesn't exist.